# How to create/view/delete a record in the custom object from salesforce UI

Tags: salesforce-id

When the Custom Object doesn't have tab and any relationships then how can i possible to  create/view/delete a record in the custom object from salesforce UI...
Custom Object contains only Text fields.

Thanks,

Comment: Any reason why you can't make a tab for it ?

Comment: Only reason I can think is if the OP is up against the Tab limit. But if not, just make a tab, life will be so much easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the object key prefix then you can view records of that object:

Let's say you have a custom object and its has key-prefix is `a00`. You can view its record by going to URL:

https://na9.salesforce.com/a00 (https://`sfdc_instance`.salesforce.com/`objectkeyprefix`)

Key-prefix is the first three characters of object's any record.

Comment: You can find the key prefix using the workbench: https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: @regal,@Ricky Hewitt -Thanks! that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Execute Anonymous window in the developer console and execute:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = AdBookUdfMap__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
System.debug(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() +'/'+ r.getKeyPrefix() );
```

The corresponding debug log will contain something like:

> 07:56:09:031 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|https://cs2.salesforce.com/a16

Comment: How come SF makes it so hard to access an object's page if there's no tab associated with it? Why not have a button linking to the prefix url on the custom object's view fields page?

Comment: @Arthlete I'm not sure it would be useful to all users, as admins probably want to control which pages they have access to under certain apps. I did raise the idea: [Provide an Admin page that lists all the accessible key prefixes within an Org](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlCpAAK)

Comment: I did upvote that suggestion. Thank you for linking me.